# Why serialization of simple types is so complicated?

Tags: c#, serialization

when running next code:

```
int myInt = 13;
object myObj = myInt;
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter bf = new     System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bf.Serialize(ms, myObj);
        byte[] myByteArray = ms.ToArray();
```

you get an array whose length is 54 bytes - I don't understand why don't you get a 4 bytes length array.

Even if you try to serialize the int variable (instead of the object variable) like this:
    bf.Serialize(ms, myInt);

you get the same result.
My goal is to convert different types (Int32, Int16, etc...) to byte array and therefore I cannot use

```
 BitConverter.GetBytes(myObj);
```

because it won't compile:

```
 Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.BitConverter.GetBytes(bool)' has some invalid arguments...
```

which is obvious, because the compiler cannot convert object to something else without telling it explicitly...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You don't get a 4 byte array because it's got to serialize all the information about the type as well, versioning etc. You say you want to serialize various different types - how would you tell the difference between one `int` and two `short` values, if you don't include any type information anywhere in the data *and* want to be able to serialize/deserialize without specifying the type?

If you just want to write primitives directly, use [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) and [`BinaryReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx).

If you want a more compact (and portable) binary serialization protocol, you might consider using Protocol Buffers (or various other serialization options).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `LosFormatter` or the `ObjectStateFormatter` they are specialized for primitive types. Using your example will result in an array of size 8 and 4